# Google sheets timestamps issues after open file

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i have formula in cell E10 -  =IFS(D10="";"";E10="";NOW();FALSE;E10)

Formula is correct and return current time and hour, but today after open file i see changed time in cell. Befor it was 07:15, now is 11:23 time. I have set file to 1 iterations and data zone is correct.

What is the problem?

Comment: This is to be expected, as per [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981?hl=en): `Note that NOW is a volatile function, updating on every edit made to the spreadsheet` and `NOW will always represent the current date and time the last time the spreadsheet was recalculated, rather than remaining at the date and time when it was first entered.`

Comment: OK, but i set on D10 cell value and not change it, in E10 is the same formula how above. Spreadsheet update function "now()" the function will run only once? Why spreadsheet recaltulate this formula after open file?

Comment: Because this is how it is implemented by Google - see documentation.